# Try to sending a post request with multithreading, it does the same request 2 times in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, request, python-multithreading

I made a post request with a file.

```
import requests
import requests as reqs
from threading import *
from itertools import islice
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

account = "file.txt"

loaded = len(open(account, encoding = "ISO-8859-1").readlines())
```

file.txt =
1
2
3
4
5

```
class check1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        with open(account) as lines:
            for lines in islice(lines, 0, loaded, 8):
                check(lines)


class check2(Thread):
    def run(self):
        with open(account) as lines:
            for lines in islice(lines, 1, loaded, 8):
                check(lines)


class check3(Thread):
    def run(self):
        with open(account) as lines:
            for lines in islice(lines, 2, loaded, 8):
                check(lines)

            
workers = [check1(), check2(), check3()]
for worker in workers:
    worker.start()
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

file.txt
1
2
3
4
5

normally I have 8 threading. but I've written three here.
result:

```
1 success
1 success
2 success
3 success
2 success
3 success
etc
```

but i want

```
1 success
2 success
3 success
4 success
5 success
```

different threads doing the same checking

how can i fix?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is you probably want `check(line)` rather than `check(lines)` in each of your functions.

But you really want something like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def check(line): 
   ...

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    with open(account, "r") as lines:
        executor.map(check, lines)
```